# Androind on BroadcastReceiver's onReceive how to recreate pending intent, if request_code is unavailable?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

Aim - To create multiple Alarms and stop the Alarm when received.

To create pendingIntent (PendingIntent.getBroadcast()) we need a request_id to uniquely identify the alarm/intent.

How to identify an Alarm in onReceive() method? onReceive() method provides context and intent variables only not the request_code.

For now I am putting request_code into the intent's extra and fetching it in onReceive() and recreating the pending intent and stopping the alarm system service.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you're not setting a repeating alarm, it will stop itself after it fires. Otherwise, the way your doing it is just how you should do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!.
I am setting repeating alarm.

Comment: The method you are using is just fine.